# Exception handling in terminate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, exception, terminate

I have the following terminate handler:

```
void on_terminate() 
{
    std::exception_ptr eptr = std::current_exception();
    if (eptr)
    {
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) 
        {
            DBG_FAIL(e.what());        
        }
        catch (...) 
        {
            DBG_FAIL("Unknown exception.");  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DBG_FAIL("Terminate was called.");
    }    
}
```

I have been using this handler for a while now and I strongly believe that it worked. But recently it appears that when an exception is throw unhanded I still end up at `"Terminate was called."`. (I still get a useful call stack.)

I am experiencing the issue on VS2015 Up3 and did not yet have time to check other compilers and platforms. (GCC on Cygwin does not implement exception_ptr yet.) Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Given the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    std::set_terminate(on_terminate);

    throw std::runtime_error("#yolo");
}
```

You can test the issue.

For completeness here you can find my [dbg.h](https://gist.github.com/rioki/85ca8295d51a5e0b7c56e5005b0ba8b4).

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757161/can-a-terminate-handler-throw-an-exception

Comment: No, since eptr is null. The refereed question is about rethrowing with no active exception. This question is more specifically about std::current_exception() returns null from a terminate handler. (But thank you for the effort.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the standard says about this, but it doesn't work with VS2017 either. You can get the desired behavior by doing:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try
{
    std::set_terminate(on_terminate);

    throw std::runtime_error("#yolo");
}
catch (...) {
    std::get_terminate()();
}
```

Which will call your terminate method from within a catch, and the `std::current_exception()` in your `on_terminate` will then work.

Comment: Except, I loose the call stack. Although there is about 8 lines of junk in the call stack, so far all implementations of compiler I have seen MSC, GCC, Clang, have the entire call stack up to the point where the exception is thrown. To me that info is more valuable than the exception's message.

Comment: Yep, that's true. I got nothing then. The standard doesn't seem to be very precise. It states that `std::current_exception` returns the exception currently being handled and that `std::terminate` is called when no handler is found, but I don't see anything that says that an exception is still being handled when `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: Yes, I fear that this is the case. That is quite unfortunate, because that case a nice piece of code. It got the callstack AND the exception msg. Since I only let the "this can not happen" cases throw into main, the callstack has prio over the message.
I will mark this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems that both gcc and Clang do it the right way, and from section 15.3.7 of the C++11 standard states that an implicit handler is considered active when `std::terminate` or `std::unexpected` is called. It seems that VS is wrong, and I did find a bug on msconnect, but it was closed as a duplicate and I can't find the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The point of `set_terminate` is that it could catch exceptions thrown from static initialization constructors, something that wrapping `main` in a try-block won't help with.

Comment: @ybungalobill And how would you call set_terminate in time for it to be active while static initialization is happening?

Comment: @evan: by putting it in a constructor of a static object. Statics are guaranteed to be initialized in order within one translation unit. Same way `std::ios_base::Init` work.